# Writing seemingly same array to two image files leads to different results

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, tiff

I'm trying to read and write tiff-images with the PIL library. While testing, I noticed that saving the seemingly same numpy array generated in different ways leads to different images on disk. Why is this and how can I fix it?

---

For testing purposes, I created an [image with GIMP (upscaled from 8x8)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xVx4.png) which I saved as TIF, read to a numpy array and wrote back to a tif file:

```
img_gimp = Image.open('img_gimp.tif')
imgarray_gimp = np.array(img_gimp)

img_gimp = Image.fromarray(imgarray_gimp, mode = 'I;16')
img_gimp.save('final_gimp.tif')
```

The result is as expected, it is the same image as the original. So far so good.

---

Now I generated the same image directly in python code:

```
imgarray_direct = np.zeros(shape = (8, 8)).astype(int)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        image[i][j] = 65535
```

Writing this array to disk...

```
img_direct = Image.fromarray(imgarray_direct, mode = 'I;16')
img_direct.save('final_direct.tif')
```

doesn't give me the expected result, instead I find this:
[image generated by for loop (upscaled from 8x8)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8uY6.png)

Doing

```
print(np.array_equal(imgarray_gimp, imgarray_direct))
```

gives `True`, and looking at `print(imgarray_gimp)` and `print(imgarray_direct)`, one cannot see any difference.

Is this intended behaviour? If yes, whats the reason for it?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Your question is quite jumbled up and I don't see any GIMP code. Can you maybe make three distinct sections, separate the sections with 3 adjacent dashes to make a horizontal line. Maybe put your GIMP code and corresponding image in one section, then your PIL code and corresponding image in the next... and so on. Thank you.

Comment: I restructured the question, hope its clearer now. What do you mean by GIMP code? As GIMP is a graphical image editor software, I just set some pixels to white to generate the reference image linked in the post.

Comment: I am still confused as your code purports to create a TIFF file with GIMP and another TIFF file with PIL, yet you show 2 PNG files both created by GIMP? Anyway, I think you need to be more careful with your types. You create an int64 array with Numpy and then suddenly change to an int16 - try using and checking the correct type consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MarkSetchell hinted in the comments, the issue is that your `dtype` for the numpy array of raw data does not match the PIL image `mode` string you are supplying afterwards. Changing the parameter passed into `astype` or simply passing in the right type on array creation fixed this issue for me. Here is what the modified code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

#Generate raw image data (16-bit!)
image_data = np.zeros(shape = (8, 8), dtype=np.uint16)#this is the big change
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        image_data[i][j] = 65535

#Save image as TIF to disk
image_direct = Image.fromarray(image_data, mode = 'I;16')
image_direct.save('final_direct.tif')
```

As a side note, I am surprised that the mode string `I;16` you have used is valid; I could not find any mention about it in [pillow's documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was exactly the problem and explains the wrong output perfectly. Wasn't thinking about numpy-specific types. 

I found this mode string as I opened the tif files that I'm planning to read, they came from some lab software. `image.mode` gave me "I;16". I also wondered why the documentation doesn't say anything about it, but I just used it to save files that are the same as the source files.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Modified the code to fix this, thanks for catching that!